# MFC resources Vista vs Win7 compatibility

Tags: windows-7, mfc, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista

Original app was developed with VS6 MFC for WinXP - then ported to VS 2005 Vista, and runs fine in Vista.  However, when installed in Win7 the app runs without crashing but the UI is scrambled.  Windows controls all seem to line up on left edge of main window.
Can this app created with VS2005 in Vista run properly in Win7?  Or does it need to be compiled and linked in Win7 to run properly in Win7?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that your program has bugs in it, or rather it makes assumptions about Windows that aren't valid: a correctly written program built on an old system with an old version of Visual Studio will work fine on Windows 7. As ever, just because something worked on old versions of Windows doesn't prove it's "right".

There aren't any easy shortcuts for this: you're going to have to debug your application to figure out what is wrong with it.